# JAXB code generation: restricted type -> how to remove a zero occurrence field?

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb, xjc

I use JAXB 2.1 to generate Java classes from several XSD files that I cannot modify (coming from a WSDL file actually), and I have a problem related to complex type restriction.
On of the restrictions modifies the occurence configuration from `minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"` to `minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="0"`. Thus this field is not needed anymore in the restricted type. But actually JAXB generates the restricted class with a [0..1] cardinality instead of 0.

By the way the generation is tuned with `<xjc:treatRestrictionLikeNewType />` so that a XSD restriction is not mapped to a Java class inheritance.

Here is an example:

Here is the way a field is defined in a complex type A:

`<element name="qualifier" type="CR" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>`

Here is the way the same field is restricted in another complex type B that restricts A:

`<element name="qualifier" type="CR" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="0"/>`

In the A generated class I have:

`@XmlElement(name = "qualifier")

protected List<CR> qualifiers;`

And in the B generated class I have:

`protected CR qualifiers;`

With my poor understanding of JAXB the absence of the `XmlElement` annotation tells JAXB not to marshall/unmarshall this field. Am I wrong?
If I am right is there a way to tell JAXB not to generate the `qualifiers` field at all?
This would be in my opinion a much better generation as it respects the constraints.

Any idea, thougths on the topic?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the type is not needed then alone **minOccurs="0" should be enough**, no ? Looks like you are trying to define an element that may not be included in the document - that does not make sense, although it's valid.

Comment: Yes you're right but I do not have the hand on the XSD files.
I have to deal with it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out.

This is basically an interaction issue between the `<xjc:treatRestrictionLikeNewType />` customization and the `<xjc:simple />` one. If I remove the simple one the fields are not generated anymore!

That's what happens when you walk on the experimental path of JAXB ;)